# .click .mouseover .mousout combined - css wont do it (not child)?

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, mouseover, mouseout

Short question:I Cant get this to work:

```
 $(".work").click(function(){
      $(".wrapper").toggleClass("wrapper-view");
      $(".content").toggleClass("content-view");})
           .mouseover(function(){
      $(".wrapper").css("left", "90%");
      $(".close").css("right", "0%");
  })       .mouseout(function(){
      $(".wrapper").css("left", "95%");
      $(".close").css("right", "-5%");
  });
```

css solution like ">" & "+"

```
.work:hover > .wrapper { left: 95%; }
```

wont work cause its not a sibling or child

how can i fix it.

my html is like:

```
<div class="wrapper">... some content...</div>
<div class="cv">
<div class="nav">
<a class="work">Work</a>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my snippit where i cant get it to work:
maybe you have any suggestions :

```js
$(".work").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("wrapper-view");
  $(".content").toggleClass("content-view");
});
$(".work").mouseover(function() {
  $(".wrapper").css("left", "90%");
  $(".close").css("right", "0%");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(".wrapper").css("left", "95%");
  $(".close").css("right", "-5%");
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
top:0;
left:200px;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color:#f4f4f4;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
z-index:2;
}
.wrapper-view{left:95%}
.cv{
top:0;
left:0;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color:blue;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
}
a{ color: white}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-view">... some content...</div>
<div class="cv">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="work" href="#">Work</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `href` was missing for the hyperlink. `.wrapper` didn't have a position assigned and there was an error in your jQuery script.

By the way, `.close` is not used in the HTML.

```js
$(".work").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("wrapper-view");
  $(".content").toggleClass("content-view");
});
$(".work").mouseover(function() {
  $(".wrapper").css("left", "90%");
  $(".close").css("right", "0%");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(".wrapper").css("left", "95%");
  $(".close").css("right", "-5%");
});
```

```css
.wrapper, .close {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">... some content...</div>
<div class="cv">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="work" href="#">Work</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i added a snippet in the question, your answer only works for hover not for click

Comment: The click works fine (the class is added and removed), but the result is the same as the hover. Change .wrapper-view{left:50%} and you will see the difference.

Comment: mhhh... in my snippet it does not work, or where am i wrong? when i click the work button, it doesnt move to position left: 50%

Comment: okay i got this far now:  the mouseout event, ruins the click event. is their a way to prevent this to happen?